# c# Web Application loses user context when using custom routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, iroutehandler

I am building a non-mvc website using **C#** and **ASP.NET** 3.5.  I have custom routes working well, and have done the same on other sites.  I also have forms authentication working well and have used forms authentication on other sites, but never both at the same time.

On this site http://ec2-23-20-231-127.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ I can login (user/pass = demo/demo) and have a user context as long as I am on a page which contains .aspx.  For example if I go to `www.mysite.com/default.aspx` I have a user context.

To test this : `Request.IsAuthenticated` returns *true* and `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated* also returns *true*.

But if I go to `www.mysite.com/` I have no user context : `Request.IsAuthenticated` returns *false* and `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` returns `"Object not set to instance of an object"`.

I have also confirmed that the cookie is being set and can view it using Firefox.

My routes are setup as follows (in **Global.asax**):

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Add("Default", new Route("", new Brandpoint.DefaultRouteHandler()));
    routes.Add("Category", new Route("{catTitle}/", new Brandpoint.CategoryRouteHandler()));
    routes.Add("Article", new Route("{catTitle}/{articleTitle},{articleId}", new Brandpoint.ArticleRouteHandler()));
}
```

Forms Authentication is setup as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="BrandpointContent" path="/" loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="5000000"></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Setting the cookie is simply:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("USERS-ID-HERE", true);
```

I'm fairly well versed in both routes and forms auth, but this has me stumped.

Anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: Of course as soon as I posted this I found the answer in a suggested post (which i could not find by searching)  The answer was found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534162/iroutehandler-in-web-forms-routing-requests-that-require-httpcontext-user?rq=1

in your web.config->system.webServer->modules you have to add runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"

So change this:
<modules>
to this:
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">

This solved my issue.  Hopefully this will help someone else as well.

Comment: can you send us the web.config?

lol yeah figured as much :)