# Why won't IIS 6 redirect my request when it works with VS2008 development server?

Tags: asp.net, iis

here is the code in the global.asax file

```
Protected Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If LCase(Request.Path).Contains("/dir/") Then
            Dim M As Match = Regex.Match(Request.Path, "/dir/(\w*)/", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
            If M.Success Then
                Response.Redirect("https://[mystore]/select.aspx?route=" & M.Groups(1).Value)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

I can run it out of VS2008 without any issues but when i deploy the project to the server running IIS 6 it will not redirect the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS 6 will not support this functionallity so you will need to impliment an ISAPI module to do it for you.  In IIS 7 this would work fine.

Here is the module that I used: http://www.isapirewrite.com/

Answer (score -1):

I would just debug the application by attaching to the process running your site, then do a soft reset.

I would guess the logic is somehow not doing the same thing on the two different environments, but you won't be able to tell unless you debug it.